# PowerShell: 'MemberOf' outputs a blank column instead of the 'Group Name' of the users

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

The below PowerShell script iterates through the groups listed in the test.csv file.
It pulls samAccountName and distinguishedName from each user in the various groups. However, when I try to pull groupName the output is "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection". Not sure how to fix this-

```
$groups = Get-Content test.csv
$domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains

foreach ($group in $groups)
{
    foreach ($domain in $domains)
    {
        if (Get-ADGroup $group -Server $domain)
        {
            Get-ADGroupMember $group -Server $domain | select groupName, samAccountName, distinguishedName | Export-Csv c:\temp\file.csv -notypeinformation -append
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the below, but it just outputs an empty column instead:

```
$groups = Get-Content test.csv
$domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains

foreach ($group in $groups)
{
    foreach ($domain in $domains)
    {
        if (Get-ADGroup $group -Server $domain)
        {
            Get-ADGroupMember $group -Server $domain | select samAccountName, distinguishedName | 
        Get-ADUser @{name  = ‘MemberOf’;’expression={$_.MemberOf -join “;”}} | 
        Export-Csv c:\temp\file.csv -notypeinformation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait I think I misread your code, are you looking to bring the user's full membership of the members of the groups in the csv?

Comment: I'm looking to list out the 'Group Name' as well as the 'samAccountName' and 'distinguishedName' for each user. I tried pulling using 'memberOf' though I could've been going in the wrong direction

Comment: if it's only the `GroupName` they're member of from those groups in the CSV then my code should work fine, if its their **Full Membership** then it would need some additions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I added some optimization to your code :)

**Note, `try {...} catch {...}`** is more or less needed here because both cmdlets `Get-ADGroup` and `Get-ADGroupMember` **will** throw if the object is not found.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$groups = Get-Content test.csv
$domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains

$result = foreach ($group in $groups)
{
    foreach ($domain in $domains)
    {
        try
        {
            $adGroup = Get-ADGroup $group -Server $domain
            $members = (Get-ADGroupMember $adGroup -Server $domain).where({
                
                # Here, I assume your looking only for user objects
                # since you're next cmdlet is Get-ADUser
                $_.ObjectClass -eq 'user' 
            
            })
            
            foreach($user in $members)
            {
                # !!! $adUser = Get-ADUser $user >> This is not needed,
                # Get-ADGroupMember already brings you the samAccountName of
                # each object

                # Here you can cast the result, I assume
                # you want your CSV to have the Name of the Group and
                # the samAccountName and distinguishedName of each user

                [pscustomobject]@{
                    GroupName = $adGroup.Name
                    samAccountName = $user.samAccountName
                    distinguishedName = $user.distinguishedName
                }

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Warning $_
        }
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv c:\temp\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks! I added an additional modification to pull across domains using global catalog but I get the error that "the operation is not supported on global catalog port". Would you be able to help?

Comment: @jack_n8778 I think you should create a new question displaying the error you're getting in addition with the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your select statement to:

```
select-object @{n='groupName';expression={$group}}, samAccountName, distinguishedName
```

It should output the $group input of Get-ADGroupMember for that column.